# Pass array of arrays as parameter in solidity function

Tags: solidity, truffle

I've this function:

```
  function addPool(PoolInput calldata _pool, uint256[] calldata _groupIds,
    uint256[] calldata _issueNumberOffsets, uint256[] calldata _caps,
    Price[][] memory _prices) external hasValidPermit(UNIVERSAL, POOL) {

    updatePool(nextPoolId, _pool, _groupIds, _issueNumberOffsets, _caps,
      _prices);

    // Increment the ID which will be used by the next pool added.
    nextPoolId = nextPoolId.add(1);
  }
```

and I want to pass the parameters using truffle, how could the price be passed??

The price is this struct:

```
 struct Price {
    AssetType assetType;
    address asset;
    uint256 price;
  }
```

Comment: You seems to can’t do it if the for variable‑length arrays…